# Mockito and Spring in Reactive Application

Tags: spring, kotlin, mockito, project-reactor, reactive

i haven't worked with Mockito at all, and with spring i am just starting (have experience with Micronaut). here is my simplified code:

```
@Service
class ServiceToBeMocked {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var pool: WorkerPool

    fun methodWithoutArguments(): Flux<Int> {
        return Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4).publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(pool))
    }

    fun methodWithArgument(list: List<Int>): Flux<Int> {
        return Flux.fromIterable(list).publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(pool))
    }
}
```

```
@Service
class ParentService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var service:ServiceToBeMocked

    fun withOutArguments(): Flux<Int> {
        return service.methodWithoutArguments().map { it*10 }
    }
    fun withArguments(): Flux<Int> {
        return service.methodWithArgument(listOf(10,20,30,40,50))
    }
}
```

```
@Service
class WorkerPool : Executor {

    private val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(60)
    override fun execute(command: Runnable) {
        executor.execute(command)
    }
}
```

and the tests:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class ParentServiceTest {
    @MockBean
    private lateinit var serviceToBeMocked: ServiceToBeMocked
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var service: ParentService
    @Test
    fun withOutArguments() {
        Mockito.`when`(serviceToBeMocked.methodWithoutArguments()).thenReturn(Flux.just(5, 6, 88))
        Mockito.`when`(serviceToBeMocked.methodWithArgument(listOf())).thenReturn(Flux.just(5, 6, 88))

        StepVerifier.create<Int> { service.withOutArguments() }
            .expectNext(5)
            .expectNext(6)
            .expectNext(88)
            .verifyComplete()
        val result=service.withArguments().collectList().block()
        println(result)
    }
}
```

Basically when i run the test with StepVerifier, then i end up in infinite loop (i cancelled the tests after 10 minutes) but in case when i comment out the step verifier, than i am getting following error:
`Cannot invoke "reactor.core.publisher.Flux.collectList()" because the return value of "refrigeration.components.selector.tmp.ParentService.withArguments()" is null`

How should i mock the service with reactor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in this code is as follows:

```kotlin
`when`(serviceToBeMocked.methodWithArgument(listOf()))
```

which means: when `methodWithArgument` is called with parameter `listOf()` (empty list) - then ...

But in your case, the list is not empty. Instead you can use matcher: `any()` or `anyList()`:

```kotlin
`when`(serviceToBeMocked.methodWithArgument(anyList()))
```

---

### Additional note:

I would strongly suggest to not use the field injection but the constructor injection instead, so you can write simple, and fast test only for this service, without need to boot the whole spring context:

```
@Service
class ParentService(private val service:ServiceToBeMocked) {
    // all the functions
}
```

and then write a simple, plain junit test (without @SpringBootTest):

```
class ParentServiceTest {

    private val serviceToBeMocked = Mockito.mock(ServiceToBeMocked::class.java)

    private val service = ParentService(serviceToBeMocked)

    // now do your tests
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this i cannot do as there are also test containers that i have to use. However i tried your solution and it bearded no different results.

Comment: ok, I just found the problem: `when(serviceToBeMocked.methodWithArgument(listOf()))` - in this case you stub only when the argument is empty list (`listOf()`) - but in your case, the list is not empty. Instead you can use matcher: `any()` or `anyList()` - I will add this to the answer